# Converting depth of irregular shape to equal given volume

Tags: geometry, volume

I have a 3D shape with the following aerial view:

[image: shape layout]

Where $a\ b\ c\ d\ e$ are known integers. The shape has a depth $f$ and volume $v$.

The question is, given a required volume $V$ where $V<v$, to the nearest integer, how much of $a$ can be converted to depth $g$ starting from left to right where $g<f$ ?

What I've tried:

The first thing I tried was to calculate: $$\frac{v-V}{(b+e*\frac da)*(f-g)}$$

This gets pretty close but doesn't really work because it tries to flatten the shape to a rectangle which assumes the whole width will always be converted, which isn't necessarily the case.

I've tried a few other ways like converting all of the $a*b$ shape that can be converted first and then trying to add on the extra bit due to the $d*e$ shape but without any success.

Comment: a is a length. How can you convert it to a depth?

Comment: @insipidintegrator sorry should have made it clearer, at the moment the shape has a depth 'f' for the entire length of 'a', so the question is how can 'a' be split into 'a1' and 'a2' where a = a1 + a2 and the depth of 'a1' is 'f' and the depth of 'a2' is 'g'

Comment: Please also differentiate between V and $\nu$.  Also, suppose I change the RHS of the box to some depth , will the box represented by d and e also change?

Comment: @insipidintegrator 'v' is the volume of the shape when the depth of the entire shape is 'f'. 'V' is the target volume that should be arrived at by converting as much depth as possible to from 'f' to 'g'

Comment: Please answer my second question too. If I take, say 1 m from the right to convert to g, does 1 m of  the box of dimensions d x e also get depressed to g?

Comment: @insipidintegrator yes it would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**CASE 1**: We start from the right. Let the length converted to $g$ be x.
**Subcase 1**: $x\leq d$. The new volume will be $$x(b+e)g+(d-x)(b+e)f + (cbf)$$ $$=(b+e)(g-f)x+d(b+e)f+cbf$$ If we equate this with $V$, then we get the range of $V$ (Using $x\in [0,d]$): $(bd+ed+bc)f=v\geq V\geq d(b+e)g+bcf$.

For this case,
$$x=\frac{V-(db+ed+cb)f}{(b+e)(g-f)}=\frac{v-V}{
(b+e)(f-g)}$$ which is pretty close to what you did.

**Subcase 2**: $x\geq d$. Then the new volume will be $$d(b+e)g +(x-d)bg+(a-x)bf.$$$$=b(g-f)x +abf-dbg+d(b+e)g$$$$=b(g-f)x +abf+deg=b(g-f)x+(v-def)+deg$$$$=b(g-f)x+v+de(g-f)=(bx+de)(g-f)+v$$ Thus, we get $x =\dfrac1b (\dfrac{v-V}{f-g}-de)$. Similarly, using $x\geq 0$, we can find the range of V achievable.

 I now hope you can solve CASE 2 (Start from left) and its subcases ($x\leq c$ and $x\geq c$) by yourself by breaking the box into parts as shown above.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with this. In Subcase 1 doesn't (bd + ed + bc) * f = v. In which case given the range of V, subcase 1 is only possible if v < V meaning g > f. I tried creating some dummy values and then finding x for both subcase 1 and 2 and for subcase 1 I got x > d and for subcase 2 I got x < d. I think I may be misunderstanding your answer

Comment: No you haven’t, I have made a mistake by considering g-f to be positive. I shall correct it asap.

Comment: Thanks, Subcase 1 works fine now and I've worked out the range for V in subcase 2 as (ab+de)g <= V < d(b+e)g+bcf. However, the calculation for x doesn't work for me, it is undercalculating how much can be converted and x dips below d for some values of V

Comment: Could you provide me with an example? I’m having trouble finding the mistake in my calculations

Comment: here's the [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PY_sLpQxm3HslgMbrsNsb6vgKJPHf4AymDpgDBaOlDo/edit?usp=sharing) I was using. The example is with a=10, b=5, c=8, d=2, e=2, f=2, g=1 and V = 93

Comment: Considering your data, 54<V<94, and x=2.2>d=2. I suggest you recheck your calculations.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake, thanks a lot!